# Pandas, transform inner most index into a json string column or a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For every unique combination of the first two indexes, I want all of the rows (and the index name) of their third index transformed into a json string column.

For example

```
recs = [{'id':123,'color':'orange','store':'big_mart', 'price':6}, {'id':123,'color':'orange','store':'Buckyz','price':5}, {'id':234,'color':'blue', 'store':'Gmart','price':7}]
d3 = pd.DataFrame(recs)
d3.set_index(['id','color','store'])
```

My intended output is supposed to look like something like this.

| id | color | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 'orange' | "[ {'store':'big_mart','price': 6}, {'store':'Buckyz','price':5}]" |
| 234 | 'blue' | "[{'store':'Gmart','price':7}]" |

The best I could do is this

```
d3.reset_index()
d3.groupby(['id','color']).apply(lambda x: x[['store','price']].to_json(orient='records')))

id   color 
123  orange    [{"store":"big_mart","price":6},{"store":"Buck...
234  blue                          [{"store":"Gmart","price":7}]
dtype: object
```

It works, but I'm having trouble appending the list output as a column into a deduplicated dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` "id" and "color" and then apply `to_dict` with orient parameter set to "records" to each group:

```
out = d3.groupby(['id', 'color'])[['store', 'price']].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).astype(str).reset_index(name='new_col')
```

or use `to_json` (saves conversion to type str):

```
out = d3.groupby(['id', 'color'])[['store', 'price']].apply(lambda x: x.to_json(orient='records')).reset_index(name='new_col')
```

Output:

```
    id   color                                            new_col
0  123  orange  [{'store': 'big_mart', 'price': 6}, {'store': 'Buckyz', 'price': 5}]
1  234    blue                   [{'store': 'Gmart', 'price': 7}]
```

Comment: Cool trick: when you `reset_index` on a series, you can pass `name='new_name'` instead of `.map({0:'new_name'})` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cols = ['id', 'colors']
new_df = d3.groupby(cols).apply(lambda x: x.drop(cols, axis=1).to_dict('records')).reset_index(name='new_col')
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
    id   color                                            new_col
0  123  orange  [{'store': 'big_mart', 'price': 6}, {'store': ...
1  234    blue                   [{'store': 'Gmart', 'price': 7}]
```